# Would it be valid to assert on mockito spyed object?

Tags: junit, mockito

I am spying an object like:

```
@Spy
@InjectMocks
private final A a= new A()
```

and in test case I am asserting on properties of A object.
As spying an object means calling real methods, would it be right to asserting on properties of spyed objects?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Does it work? If it works and it expresses what you want to test, then yes, it's valid.

Comment: Hi skaffman, yes it is working. I was just wondering because, if I inspect the value of spyed variable, it shows a mocked value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it will work, but I recommend against it, it's usually a bad idea (even an anti-pattern) to mock value object.

- If the test is to verify properties have changed to specific values then this object is the tested object and as such there would be no reason for it to be a spy.
- If creating a simple value object is too difficult with the current API, then there's a usability problem in the tested code, refactoring or utility is needed to create valid instances easily.

*Only in some very specific edge cases one would need the combination of a `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks`.* Most the time it is not needed, and such tests show a design issue in the tested code.

Instead just create a real object, inject mocks if needed and assert properties directly on the tested object. A good spy usage would be verifying that there was interactions between two *collaborating* objects only.